# What should the payload have? Mule ESB - Studio

Tags: api, mule, esb, payload

Im new at Mule. I saw some examples of people who had all the information stored in this part of the message called 'payload', Mule Doc is not the greatest so i hope you can explain me this.

I have seen that they recive the information and access to it this way

```
  #[payload.age]
```

but in my case (just trying) I discovered that my information (that comes from the http POST request ) is accesible this way

```
  #[message.inboundProperties.age]
```

What's the diferece? im always getting a payload with information  that i dont know anything about.

in this image i show you a simple flow of my App, just as example.

[image]

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the documentation for Mule is now very solid.

Here is a great explanation of the structure of a Mule message: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Message+Structure

You can't really use Mule without having some fundamentals: I strongly suggest you got through these first steps http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Fundamentals

Comment: Is solid but it lacks of examples, i cant really understand ehat informstion does the payload carry.

Comment: Typically, it's whatever came from an `inbound-endpoint` or a `set-payload`.

Comment: it was certification exam question: what does the payload of a Mule message always contain? Ans: a) A json data, b) xml data c) A java object implementing the collection interface( such as ArrayList) d) A java object determined by the message source and processors. 
what is the answer for this?